# What's the purpose of `:hover::before`?

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm looking at a html + css button, but I'm confused on why the before pseudo-element was used with the hover pseudo-class.

```css
.anchor-style {
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 270px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ff0072;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.anchor-style::before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  background-color: #ff0072;
  z-index: -2;
}

.anchor-style:hover::before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor-style" target="_blank" href="http://www.infinity2o.com">
    Say Hi to My New Matches
</a>
```

There's already a regular style on the anchor tag, why would you need even more styling with a before pseudo-element?

I tried looking at the before pseudo-element documentation and understood that it would be useful for adding elements before each p tag... but I don't understand how it gets interpreted differently for the button.

Comment: the pseudo element is creating the background effect, simply read the CSS and check each property, change them, test, etc and you will understand ... by the way we can do without

Comment: You could try applying the styling without `:before` and comparing the results.

Comment: if you're going to down vote my question, at least tell me why

Comment: @Hunter690 FYI you probably got downvoted by someone who was looking at the first part of your question and thought it was too subjective or would provide subjective answers. SO wants all questions to be extremely specific with a definitive problem and prompt extremely specific, data driven answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for animation effect. The use of `::before` is also *cleaner*.

> The ::before selector inserts something before the content of each selected element(s).

So you can think of the `::before` pseudo as an empty `div`. The following is equivalent without the `::before` pseudo

```css
.anchor-style {
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 270px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ff0072;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  background-color: #ff0072;
  z-index: -2;
}

.anchor-style:hover > .before {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor-style" target="_blank" href="http://www.infinity2o.com">
    <div class="before"></div>
    Say Hi to My New Matches
</a>
```

Comment: thank you for the example; why would you need: the .before class at all. Couldn't you just change `.anchor-style:hover > .before` to be this `.anchor-style:hover > div` and then move all the extra stuff in the .before into `.anchor-style:hover > div`?

Comment: @Hunter690 sure, the `before` class was just for demonstration.

Comment: oh okay, but why can't you just do `.anchor-style:hover {}` and include all of that stuff in there?

Comment: @Hunter690, because when you hover you want to *target* the `div` and apply styles to it. It's the `div` that's making the *background-fading* effect.